# How should I say "range over", as in math?

Tags: mathematics

I've been checking several Italian books of logic and math to find some expression equivalent to "range over" as in the following mathematical expression:

> Let *x*, *y*, and *z* be variables that **range over** the natural numbers.

I haven't found an equivalent expression so far, but this is the best I could come up with:

> Siano *x*, *y* e *z* variabili che **vanno su**i numeri naturali.

> Siano *x*, *y* e *z* variabili che **spaziano tra** i numeri naturali.

What would be a better equivalent for this?

Comment: What about "... sono elementi dei numeri naturali" = "...are elements of the natural numbers"?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: ... appartenenti all'insieme dei numeri naturali (https://books.google.es/books?id=4nWLBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&dq=%22appartiene+all%27insieme+dei+numeri+naturali%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXyqTgwtv0AhXRgs4BHSMpAC0Q6AF6BAgBEAE#v=onepage&q=%22appartiene%20all'insieme%20dei%20numeri%20naturali%22&f=false)? Ma forse si potrebbe riscrivere la frase in modo più semplice, qualcosa come "Siano le variabili *x*, *y* e *z* numeri naturali" (non sono per niente sicura che questa frase suoni bene alle orecchie di un italiano; infatti, neanche a me suona del tutto bene).

Comment: Attenzione @GiuseppeRomanazzi, i naturali non sono un corpo, non sono neppure un anello, quindi non si può usare il termine "campo" in questo contesto (che, peraltro, è un sostantivo e no un verbo come "range over").

Comment: Besides, in Italian this kind of algebraic assertions are commonly introduced with the *participio passato* of the verb "dare".

Comment: I'd say neither proposal is common usage. Possibly “Siano *x*, *y*, *z* variabili che denotano numeri naturali” is better; perhaps also ”Siano *x*, *y*, *z* variabili nei numeri naturali”.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write my previous comments in English. Thanks, @egreg, as I've said, I was trying to rewrite the sentence in a simpler way, but I didn't know how to do it.

Comment: @Charo Grazie Prof, la matematica è il tuo "campo". Quindi dici sono improprie le espressioni che vengono usate spesso come "nel campo dei numeri reali", "nel campo dei numeri primi", ecc.? Oppure ho sbagliato a indicare il punto 5d?

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi:  Certamente si può dire "questo matematico lavora nel campo dei numeri primi", ma questo uso di "campo" non corrisponde all'accezione 5d del Treccani che define "campo" in algebra come sinonimo di "corpo commutativo". Si tratterebbe invece dell'accezione 6.

Comment: @Charo Grazie, ma non intendevo cambiare contesto. Un esempio che si può trovare [qui](https://www.lezionidimatematica.net/Esponenziali_Logaritmi/lezioni/esponenziali_logaritmi_lez_02.htm), ma ce ne sono molti altri, è: "**Vediamo quali valori assume la funzione, al variare di x nel campo dei numeri reali**". O anche nell'[Enciclopedia della Matematica](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/identita-di-lagrange_%28Enciclopedia-della-Matematica%29/) "**Nel campo dei numeri reali (o in quello dei numeri complessi), è la relazione ...**".

Comment: Sì, @GiuseppeRomanazzi, i reali e anche i complessi sono un "campo", cioè, un "corpo commutativo", ma i naturali non lo sono.

Comment: @Charo Grazie, cancello subito il mio commento in modo che non inganni nessuno.

Comment: I'd also say something like “Siano *x*, *y* e *z* variabili che variano sui/nei numeri naturali”, which is not too elegant due to the repetition _variabile/variare_ but expresses better the “range over” idea, rather than just *x*, *y* e *z* being elements of N.

Comment: Questa domanda mi sta facendo studiare matematica Andrebbe bene quanto segue? "Date le variabili x, y e z appartenenti all'insieme dei numeri naturali ...", "Dati i numeri naturali x, y e z ...", entrambe corrispondenti alla notazione {x,y,z} ∈ N.

Comment: Maybe rephrasing it as "*Siano x, y e z variabili il cui valore è incluso fra i numeri naturali*" ("Let x, y, and z be variables whose values range over/is included in the natural numbers.") could work.

Comment: @DaG Grazie, correggo con {x,y,z} ⊆ N.

Answer (score 4):

*Appartengono* is the equivalent. Range over means that they are inside the specified range and we use 'appartenere' when we refer to something included inside a set of elements (in math). Anyways, it's more likely that you'll find something like that in an Italian book:

> Siano x, y, z numeri naturali.

Rarely you'll find something like:

> Siano x, y, z appartenenti all'insieme dei numeri naturali.

Unless you are in a section that's talking about set theory

Comment: Sorry, but I fully disagree: the question is about logic, where variables belong to nothing at all.

Comment: @egreg Are you sure the question really belongs strictly only to logic? It is tagged [tag:mathematics] and states just that OP is actually looking in _"several Italian books of logic and mathematics"_ for the equivalent of... I'm afraid it might depend on the context. Maybe it is the case to ask the OP for some more explanation. (Just by reading - as it is - the question I would also have said  _variabili che appartengono ai numeri naturali_... Since you obviously see more, when you can find some time could you explain it better?)

Comment: I was thinking the same

Comment: The problem I find in this proposal is that you are not saying that *x*, *y* and *z* are ***variables*** that take values over **N**.

Comment: You can say: "Il gatto è un mammifero" or "Il gatto appartiene alla categoria dei mammiferi". Same concept, different ways of translating or communicating. The question was about not finding most of the times an equivalent expression for "Range over", which is, in my opinion, true. And that's cause most of the times it gets lost in the translation process due to its light redundancy.

Comment: What you said is also true, but it's implied that x, y and z take values over N

Comment: @LorenzoMartini The word “logic” appears in the initial paragraph of the question. In mathematical logic the word “variable” has a very specific technical meaning and you can't generally omit it, because the distinction between “variable” and “term” is fundamental.

Comment: I agree with egreg and Charo that this answer is flawed. Your Italian sentences are meaningful, but with a different meaning than the English one the OP is asking about. As already remarked, variable don't _belong_ to, say, naturals. They belong to a set of variables {*x*, *y*, whatever}. For instance, one couldn't say that the polynomial 3 *x* + 2 *y* belongs to the naturals, even if we required *x* and *y* to range over naturals.

Comment: I know that I shouldn't comment about this, as comments are expected to be only "useful and in-topic", but I feel this whole post so fascinating with the involving aspects of logic, math and language. If this was even going to be a cross-post with music.SE I believe I could just "esplodere" :-)